# selenium common exception:timeout exception message how to rectify it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
import time

class Login:
    def __init__(self, driver, username, password):
        self.driver = driver
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    def signin(self):
        print('opening')
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
        uid = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#react-root > section > main > article > div.rgFsT > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > input')))
        uid.click()
        uid.send_keys(self.username)
        pswd = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > article > div.rgFsT > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > input')
        pswd.click()
        pswd.send_keys(self.password)
        btn = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > article > div.rgFsT > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(4)')
        btn.click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need to look into your source code. Can you please try pasting your CSS selector in Chrome dev tools and see if the element is highlighted. I am guessing either the element is not loaded in 10 secs or the CSS selector is not correct. Would it also be possible to provide the HTML? so we can look it and see if we can shorten the selector

Answer (score 0):

Module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no 'presence_of_elements_located' member; maybe 'presence_of_element_located'?

```
uid = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > input')))
        uid.click()
        uid.send_keys(self.username)
```